# tv:start/0 undefined in Erlang/OTP 17 Eshell v6?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

How to view mnesia table in Erlang/OTP v17. I tried using `tv:start()` but the shell returns `undefined function`. Looks like `tv` module no longer exists. What to use in place of it?

Comment: The following applications were removed: `appmon`, `pman`, `toolbar`, `tv`. The `ose` application was added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the observer module should replace it (tv was using the deprecated gs gui)

Comment: If you can get wx widgets to work! The old gs gui was much more portable and worked basically everywhere without effort.

Comment: I agree, although I succeed to use it on both my Windows and linux environments it cost me some effort. On my side I wrote some gui using wxWidget and gs, and I must say that I found the documentation and the example for wxWidget very poor, but the result quite nice.

Answer (score 2):

[According to Erlang docs:](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.9.3/lib/tv-2.1.4.9/doc/html/tv.html) 
"The TV application has been superseded by the Observer application. TV will be removed in R16."

- instead of:  tv:strat(). , use: observer:start().

Answer (score 1):

> MODULE observer MODULE SUMMARY A GUI tool for observing an erlang
>   system. DESCRIPTION
>
> The observer is gui frontend containing various tools to inspect a
>   system. It displays system information, application structures,
>   process information, ets or mnesia tables and a frontend for tracing
>   with ttb.
>
> See the user's guide for more information about how to get started.
>
> EXPORTS
>
> start() -> ok
>
> This function starts the observer gui. Close the window to stop the
>   application.